# Replace special characters Ruby

Tags: ruby, special-characters, gsub

I want to replace all these characters: `'àáäâãèéëẽêìíïîĩòóöôõùúüûũñç'` to    `'aaaaaeeeeeiiiiiooooouuuuunc'`.

Is there a effective way to do this in Ruby? I was thinking about loop each character, but it's not effective.

Thanks.

Comment: FYI - such a conversion is called "transliteration". If you google that you will find some answers on SO and also some gems that can help (Rails also supports transliteration).

Comment: _Sidenote_: all the answers below do not take into account that actually there are two ways to get e.g. “ä” symbol. Try this in IRB: `'ä' == 'ä'`. The former one is former ASCII-8 character http://unicode-table.com/en/00E4/ , while the latter is `a` with a combining diacritics http://unicode-table.com/en/0308/

Answer (score 14, accepted):

I would use [`String#tr`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.2.0/String.html#method-i-tr) which is faster than a Regexp when replacing single characters:

```
string = 'hàllò wörld'
string.tr('àáäâãèéëẽêìíïîĩòóöôõùúüûũñç', 'aaaaaeeeeeiiiiiooooouuuuunc')
#=> '"hallo world"'
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! Works like a charm.

Answer (score 1):

#### Please note: the answer by @spickermann is better and should be considered the correct one.

```
from = 'àáäâãèéëẽêìíïîĩòóöôõùúüûũñç'
to = 'aaaaaeeeeeiiiiiooooouuuuunc'

input.gsub /[#{from}]/, from.split('').zip(to.split('')).to_h
```

Comment: I wonder if there is some unicode "simplification" helper for this? Just strip the diacritics and that's it.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev No, AFAIK. I did started a [project on that](https://github.com/mudasobwa/forkforge), it provides a complete low-level background for handling the last version of unicode, as by consortium, but since then I had no time to finish it to be at least minimum viable product :(

Comment: I upvoted your answer, anyway, that's good one also. Any answer is welcome.

Comment: @SergioTulentsev BTW, stripping the diacritics won’t work for former ASCII-8 symbols, that were left in utf-8. Try this in pry: `'ä' == 'ä'` and be surprised :)